# Save only the required CSV file using PySpark

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I am quite new to PySpark, I am trying to read and then save a CSV file using Azure Databricks.

After saving the file I see many other files like "_Committed","_Started","_Success" and finally the CSV file with a totally different name.

I have already checked using DataFrame `repartition(1)` and `coalesce(1)` but this only deals when the CSV file itself was partitioned by Spark. Is there anything that can be done using PySpark?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you write a CSV back to Azure Blob Storage using Databricks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63851044/how-do-you-write-a-csv-back-to-azure-blob-storage-using-databricks)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

> df.toPandas().to_csv(path/to/file.csv)

It will create a single file csv as you expect.

Answer (score -1):

Those are default Log files created when saving from PySpark . We can't eliminate this.
Using coalesce(1) you can save in a single file without partition.